# How to Make total of same customers orders

Tags: magento-1.9, php, admin

I have to make the total of the same customer who has many orders.
means i need the sum of all orders of 1 customer
I tried this.

```
$cus = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();
foreach($cus as $customer)
{
echo "<pre>";
$i=Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($customer->getEntityId());
echo "<pre>";
$j=($i->getstatus());
if($j == complete)
{
    print_r($i->getbaseGrandTotal());
    //print_r($i->getData());
    print_r($i->getCustomerEmail());        
}
else
{
    echo "bye";     
}}
```

Comment: What happened when you tried that? What is the problem? Looks like you're looping through the orders, verifying their status, and then accessing the grand total- why not just total them? Also, it would help you get help if you indented your code and used more complete (descriptive) variable names.

Comment: actually, i put a condition that if order status is complete than come to if condition & in if condition  I have to put the overall total of 1 customer who made multiple order  so please help me @MikelBitson

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use below code:

```
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
     ->addAttributeToFilter('customer_id', 'customerId here');

foreach ($orders as $order) {
    $total = $order->getGrandTotal();
     $sum+= $total;

}
   echo $sum ;
```

If you want order filter by order status use below code:

```
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
     ->addAttributeToFilter('customer_id', 'customerId here')
     ->addFieldToFilter('status', 'complete');

 foreach ($orders as $order) {
        $total = $order->getGrandTotal();
         $sum+= $total;

    }
       echo $sum ;
```